# What Regex for this?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I try to write a good regex, but even with documentation, I don't know how to write the good regex.

I've a lot of strings, and I need to clean theses of some characters.

For exemple :

> 70%coton/ 30%LINé

should become :

> 70%COTON-30%LINE

In fact :

- `/\#` must be replace by `-`
- Spaces must be delete
- Accentual characters must be replace without accent

How I can do this ?

Comment: Most of it is easy, however off the top of my head I imagine the accent replacement being a slight challenge.

Comment: Should spaces be deleted completely? Or converted to `-`? I.e., would `one\ two three` becone `one-two-three` or `one-twothree`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`iconv()`](http://lv.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) for accents:

```
$text = 'glāžšķūņu rūķīši';
$text = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT', $text);
echo $text; // outputs "glazskunu rukisi"
```

To do the rest, I'd add `strtoupper()` for changing case of letters, `str_replace()` to get rid of spaces and `preg_replace()` to convert those few characters to `-`:

```
$text = 'glāžšķūņu rūķīši / \\ # test';
$text = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT', $text);
$text = strtoupper($text);
$text = str_replace(' ', '', $text);
$text = preg_replace('#[/\\#\\\\]+#', '-', $text);
echo $text; // outputs "GLAZSKUNURUKISI-TEST"
```

Comment: perfect ! thanks !

But in the regex, I need to replace the , char at -, how do it ?

Comment: Replace `,` with `-`? Then just add it to other chars that need to be replaced - `'#[/,\\#\\\\]+#'`. As it is not a special character in `[]`, it does not even need to be escaped.

Comment: Why don't you use another character as delimiter if you want to use `#` inside? You also don't need four ``\`` to produce one of them. This should be fine: `'~[/#\\]+~'`

Comment: @Felix, I'm used to using `/` or `#` as delimiters, but yes, other characters may be used as well. As for having four "\" symbols, you have to pass escaped "\" to the pattern, i.e., "\\" has to be passed. But if you use "\\" in string, it results in single "\" being used in pattern because of the way how PHP parses strings. Therefore each "\" has to be escaped one more time. You can test it yourself - I got a nasty "*Warning:  preg_replace() : Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 8*" after replacing "\\\\" with "\\".

Comment: @binaryLV: Ah I got confused between double and single quotes. E.g. for escaping `#`, `\#` is fine. But you have to create two literal ``\`` for the regex, hence you need indeed four... or you could just rearrange the characters: `~[\/#]+~` will work fine and is more readable...

Comment: @Felix, while it may be more readable, it may give unexpected results, if edited without paying too much attention to what really happens. `\#` is fine because PHP leaves `\#` as `\#` after parsing the string. It does the same with `\\#`. Both `\#` and `\\#` are passed as `\#` to the `preg_replace()`. It is really matter of taste in this case. I prefer to correctly escape what has to be escaped.

Comment: By the way, single/double quotes don't have much to do with escaping "\". In both cases, "\" should (or rather *could*; matter of taste) be escaped if literal "\" is necessary in resulting string.

Answer (score 3):

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF8");

$string = '70%COTON/ 30%LINé';
$string = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string);
$string = preg_replace("#[^\w\%\s]#", "", $string);
$string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string);
$string = preg_replace('#(-){2,}#', ' ', $string);

echo strtoupper($string); // 70%COTON-30%LINE
```

Comment: You dont't need to set locale. It is safer to use `u` modifier for regular expressions.

Comment: @Felix Kling, doesn't hurt to escape :) @Karolis, it not for regex, but for `iconv`, `u` is for ungreddy...

Comment: @webarto: No, `U` is for ungreedy. `u` is for UTF-8. [List of modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Comment: @Geert, my bad, I write them like `(.*?)`, `setlocale` is for `iconv` as I have said.

Comment: @webarto: I agree, the `U` modifier should be avoided.

Comment: @webarto, do you know how `"\%"` is being used in this case? `var_dump("\%")` prints `\%` rather than `%`, is that what you expected to be passed to `preg_replace()`?

Comment: @binaryLV, I don't understand? `%` needs not to be escaped, I escaped it.. If you want to let `\` through you have to `\\\`... Code I posted works as expected.